# ¿Cómo acceder a los datos de una respuesta JSON para mostrar en el calendario de FullCalendar?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

Tengo un sistema de citas, y las mismas las quiero mostrar en un calendario, estoy trabajando con FullCalendar.

Estoy mostrando las citas en el calendario, pero cuando deseo hacer clic en la cita para mostrar los detalles, no me muestra algunos datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para el detalle obtengo los datos de las citas por medio de mi controlador y los devuelvo en formato JSON:

```
public function calendarShowDetail($id)
{
    $appointments = Appointment::findOrFail($id);
    return response()->json($appointments);
}
```

En el archivo JS los recibo de la siguiente manera

```
eventClick:function(info){

  console.log(info.event);

  axios.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/appointments/calendar/show/"+info.event.id).

  then(
    (response) => {

      document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = info.event.title;
      document.getElementById('service').innerHTML = info.event.service_id;
      document.getElementById('start').innerHTML = info.event.start;
      document.getElementById('end').innerHTML = info.event.end;
      document.getElementById('description').innerHTML = info.event.description;

      $("#calendarModal").modal("show");
    }
  )
}
```

Al imprimir `console.log(info.event);` obtengo esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y puedo acceder a algunos datos de la instancia, ejemplo el ID

Pero cuando lo muestro en el Modal, hay datos que me aparecen indefindos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ya que se encuentran en (_def: extendedProps:), y no sé como acceder a ellos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y no sé si será posible una vez obtenidos, mostrar el dato relacionado en la base de datos, ejemplo:
`info.event.service_id` es el ID relacionado a la base de datos `Services` con blade accedo de la siguiente manera `{{ $appointment->service->service }}` pero inicialmente lo importante es poder acceder a estos datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi modal

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="calendarModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Detalle de la cita</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
     </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <h6><strong>Paciente: </strong></h6>
        <h6 id="title"></h6>

        <h6><strong>Servicio: </strong></h6>
        <h6 id="service"></h6>

        <h6><strong>Hora de inicio: </strong></h6>
        <h6 id="start"></h6>

        <h6><strong>Hora de finalización: </strong></h6>
        <h6 id="end"></h6>

        <h6><strong>Descripción: </strong></h6>
        <h6 id="description"></h6>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Prueba con `document.getElementById('description').innerHTML = info.event.extendedProps.description;`

Comment: Sí funcionó, muchas gracias!... había intentado antes de preguntar con `info.event._def.extendedProps.description;` y no funcionó, ahora lo hice como lo sugeriste funcionó y tambien con el `_def`.